# Angular SSR, Dynamic Page Won't Load - Status 504

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Code: http://github.com/dbots-co/website

Directly connecting to a dynamic route (dashboard, bot page), seems to not work. However, directly connecting to docs does work.

This only happens when using Angular 10 Universal SSR.

Not Working: `https://dbots.co/bots/774811448576573480`

Working: `https://dbots.co/docs/get-started`

**bot-page.component.ts**:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.service.init();

    this.user = this.service.getBot(this.id);
    this.bot = this.service.getSavedBot(this.id);
    if (!this.user || !this.bot)
      return this.router.navigate(['']);

    this.seo.setTags({
      description: this.bot.listing.overview,
      titlePrefix: this.user.username,
      titleSuffix: 'DBots',
      url: `bots/${this.id}`
    });

    this.analytics.botPageView({ botId: this.user.id });
    
    this.themeService.setNavbarBackground('var(--background-secondary)');
    document
      .querySelector('.navbar')
      .setAttribute('style', `margin-bottom: -5px;`);
  }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    { path: 'bots/:id', component: BotPageComponent },
    ...
];
```

Comment: Your `main` is configured wrong for sure: https://github.com/DBots-co/Website/blob/stable/angular.json#L135 this should be `src\main.server.ts`. It's an error in the schematic that's not yet fixed

Comment: I also experienced that in some cases you cannot send webrequests during SSR. On IIS Express this worked fine for me, but when deployed to a Plesk installation, the SSR is broken and you have to pass the data to the angular app through the [params.data](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/main.server.ts#L52), from the [server-side](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/Startup.cs#L465)